# Convert a Bitmap image into a texture or material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aforge

I see a lot of programmers wanting to converting stuff INTO Bitmap, but I'm unable to find a suiting solution to the opposite issue.

I'm using AForge.net with Unity, and I'm trying to test it out by applying my processed image to a cube.

My current code looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public Renderer rnd;
    public Bitmap grayImage;
    public Bitmap image;
    public UnmanagedImage final;
    public byte[] test;

    Texture tx;
    void Start () {


        image = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile("rip.jpg");

        Grayscale gs = new Grayscale (0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        grayImage = gs.Apply(image);
        final = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(grayImage);

        rnd = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rnd.enabled = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        rnd.material.mainTexture = final;
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the line `rnd.material.mainTexture = final;`:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage' to 'UnityEngine.Texture'
```

I'm unclear if the Managed to Unmanaged convertion is needed.

Comment: Convert from `bmp` to texture? But you have `jpg` in your code not `bmp`

Comment: @Programmer the image becomes bmp after the grayImage = gs.Apply(image); line

Comment: You said you want to convert from bmp but you are loading a jpg file `FromFile("rip.jpg");`. Why not  try bmp? The most important question is what is the source of the bmp data? From a file, the internet(WWW or UnityWebRequest) or byte?

Comment: Aforge.NET (I haven't tried this) is supposed to have a `TextureTools.FromBitmap` method: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/0f841b8f-885d-2898-7e2b-902e77bf35ab.htm

Comment: I have a personal image which is JPG > I convert it to BMP to be able to apply AForges method(In this case make it grayscale) > Next I want to be able to use it as a texture straight from code.

Comment: using System.Drawing; // This won't be able to run on Android and iOS.

Comment: I think I found what you are looking for. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your code, the question should be "*How to convert UnmanagedImage to Texture or Texture2D*" since UnmanagedImage(`final` variable) stores the converted image from `UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage`.

[`UnmanagedImage`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/c07a1dc3-d467-5ec0-b437-2cb5a41c479f.htm) has a property called [`ImageData`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/b10cd4cc-accd-f6cb-b227-5fe850663007.htm) which returns `IntPtr`.

Luckily, [`Texture2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html), has at least, two functions that loads textures from `IntPtr`.

Your `final` variable is a type of `UnmanagedImage`.

**1**.Use Texture2D's constructor [`Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture.html) and it's complimentary function [`UpdateExternalTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.UpdateExternalTexture.html).

```
Texture2D convertedTx;
//Don't initilize Texture2D in the Update function. Do in the Start function
convertedTx = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture (1024, 1024, TextureFormat.ARGB32 , false, false, final.ImageData);

//Convert UnmanagedImage to Texture
convertedTx.UpdateExternalTexture(final.ImageData);
rnd.material.mainTexture = convertedTx;
```

**2**.Use Texture2D's [`LoadRawTextureData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html) and it's complimentary function [`Apply`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html).

```
Texture2D convertedTx;
//Don't initilize Texture2d in int the Update function. Do in the Start function
convertedTx = new Texture2D(16, 16, TextureFormat.PVRTC_RGBA4, false);

int w = 16;
int h = 16;
int size = w*h*4;

//Convert UnmanagedImage to Texture
convertedTx.LoadRawTextureData(final.ImageData, size);
convertedTx.Apply(); //Must call Apply after calling LoadRawTextureData

rnd.material.mainTexture = convertedTx;
```